# htaccess bitrix

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает редирект и как сделать что бы работал?

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 Redirect 301 /?page_id=1528 /services/mypage.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
 RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Должен получиться 301-й редирект со страницы /?page_id=1528 на страницу /services/mypage.php

RewriteCond и RewriteRule были битриксом добавлены.

Comment: А что и куда должно редиректиться?

Comment: что делает `Redirect 301 /?page_id=1528 /services/mypage.php` ?

Comment: должен получиться 301-й редирект со страницы /?page_id=1528 на страницу /services/mypage.php

Answer (score 2):

Для таких вещей в Битриксе сделан url_rewrite - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/urlrewrite.php

Answer (score -1):

Если `redirect engine` вообще работает, то вполне возможно стоит прописать 
`/ваша_папка_от_корня/?page_id=1528`